# Square depth of number in polynomial time

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

### Update

It seems that it is simply not possible to do this. Someone also sent me a copy of a different exam where almost the same question was asked, but with the difference that instead of being able to remove from any position you could remove only from beginning or start. Most likely the question was copied with an error. Now I only have to prove this and request the question exam be reevaluated.

A few weeks ago, in an examen in a course on Data Structures and Algorithms I was given the following problem. I couldn't resolve it in the given time then and although I will probably pass the course, I have been trying since yesterday to come up with a solution so I may improve my skills.

### The problem

Given an integer **n** we repeatedly eliminate a digit from any position, until we are left with a number of only one digit. The function *PC(n)* is defined as the maximum numbers of squares of integers obtainable by the described procedure.

For example *PC*(32492) = **3**. Two possible sequences are:

- 32492 -> **3249** -> **324** -> 24 -> **4**
- 32492 -> **3249** -> 349 -> **49** -> **9**

Now design an algorithm that can calculate *PC(n)* in polynomial time in **d**, where **d** is the number of digits in n. Assume you have a way to test if a number is square of an integer in O(1) time.

### What I tried so far

The first approach obviously is to test every possible sequence and return the maximum. If I'm not mistaken this is O(d!).

Improving on the brute force method, I added a HashMap where I stored all values that have already been calculated. This way we can use a O(1) lookup to avoid having to calculate the same value twice. This is obviously an improvement in real time used, but I'm having a hard time getting a lower bound on the time complexity. So, as far as I can see, this is not polynomial.

I also tried some greedy algorithm approaches, but as expected I found for every algorithm (that I could think of) a case where it didn't choose optimally.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried looking online for similar problems, but have had no luck so far.

Comment: If N is the number, then d = log10(N) is number of digits.  Time is O(d!)

Comment: I think you may be grabbing the wrong end of the problem.  I don't have time to work this out fully because of my job needs today, but for your example every perfect square must be <= 32492, so every solution must have an integer square root <= sqrt(32492), which is 180.  In other words, every candidate must be a square of the numbers 0 through 180.  Generate those squares, and see which can be created from the ordered set of digits in the original number.

Comment: @pjs that will be time `O(sqrt(N)) = O(10^(d/2))` which is exponential in `d`.  But I think that is the right idea.

Comment: Hmm, this problem seems off to me. There are an exponential number of distinct subsequences possible (e.g., if we repeat 9876543210 k times, then we can make all 10^k k-digit numbers from a sequence of length 10k, so exponential with base 10^(1/10)), so if all we have for square-testing is an opaque constant-time box, we can't possibly check all of them without invoking some nontrivial number theory, which would make it weird to mention that square-checking is constant time given that Newton's algorithm isn't particularly obscure.

Comment: @Nuclearman Generating all subsequence (non-contiguous) is O(2^d) (or O(d!) in OP) by the fact that the output (the number of subsequences) can be that long. So it's not feasible, as already mentioned in OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this answer so the question doesn't stay open. Seems to be a mistake by the teacher and not possible.

The problem was probably supposed to only allow elimination of first or last digit, in which case the problem can be solved in O(d^2) using dynamic programming.

Answer (score -1):

Tricky, tricky. The square finding aspect of this is a red herring, it's a moot point if you can check it in `O(1)`. The real problem is unique, ordered substring finding, which seems to come down to finding subsequences after a bit of wrangling with it, perhaps it's a trick question and the goal is show that it can't be done?

Comment: Where in the recursion tree does this algorithm check for squareness of the 2-digit number formed by the first and last digit?

Comment: Actually no the recursion logic is wrong in general, need to adjust overly complicated.

Comment: @justhalf Fixed, no need to split it. Just remove the index and join the two substrings. The substring check is done first across all possible substrings "as is", if that check passes, then we go a level deeper and make sure that passes as well. Technically this algorithm is a depth first search, which isn't ideal.

Comment: Hmmm, that actually makes it no longer polynomial, I believe.

Comment: This is basically searching all possible sub-sequence now XD

Comment: This isn't polynomial in d.

Comment: Hmmm, good question then. Still feels like the square finding aspect is a red herring as I don't see how that would help, but without it, it seems hard to separate what remains from simply finding all possible subsequences. Hmmm, one thing to consider.  One possibility might be in bounding the number that can be removed. Considering only unique substrings might make sense. IE: checking `1111111111` isn't terribly interesting. Hmmm perhaps the real task was to realize it was a trick question and point out that it's equivalent to checking all subsequences, and prove it.

Comment: Might also be something super hacky like "Check all substrings for all possible substrings generated by N choose K/2". Something like that would be `O(N^(K/2))`. Technically polynomial, but effectively exponential. Interested to see the exam solution for this.

Comment: @orlp Indeed, my original solution was polynomial, but didn't cover all cases, the solution that provided that coverage ended up just being finding all subsequences one way or another when I went to update the O for it, no clear path beyond that and no clear reason why a O(1) for finding if square or not would be useful (beyond being nitpicky about performance of square root finding). There might be something esoteric in number theory that might help. Only other thing I can think of is some sort of bounding approach, given the max depth, but that feels like an optimization and not a solution.